# How to extract the number after specific word using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have several lines of text. I want to extract the number after specific word using awk.

I tried the following code but it does not work.

At first, create the test file by: `vi test.text`. There are 3 columns (the 3 fields are generated by some other pipeline commands using awk).

```
Index  AllocTres                              CPUTotal
1      cpu=1,mem=256G                         18
2      cpu=2,mem=1024M                        16
3                                             4
4      cpu=12,gres/gpu=3                      12
5                                             8
6                                             9
7      cpu=13,gres/gpu=4,gres/gpu:ret6000=2   20
8      mem=12G,gres/gpu=3,gres/gpu:1080ti=1   21
```

Please note there are several empty fields in this file.
what I want to achieve is to extract the number after the first `gres/gpu=` in each line (if no `gres/gpu=` occurs in this line, the default number is `0`) using a pipeline like: `cat test.text | awk '{some_commands}'` to output 4 columns:

```
Index  AllocTres                              CPUTotal   GPUAllocated
1      cpu=1,mem=256G                         18         0
2      cpu=2,mem=1024M                        16         0
3                                             4          0
4      cpu=12,gres/gpu=3                      12         3
5                                             8          0
6                                             9          0
7      cpu=13,gres/gpu=4,gres/gpu:ret6000=2   20         4
8      mem=12G,gres/gpu=3,gres/gpu:1080ti=1   21         3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '1s/$/\tGPUAllocated/;s~.*gres/gpu=\([0-9]\).*~& \t\1~;1!{\~gres/gpu=[0-9]~!s/$/ \t0/}' input_file
Index  AllocTres                              CPUTotal  GPUAllocated
1      cpu=1,mem=256G                         18        0
2      cpu=2,mem=1024M                        16        0
3                                             4         0
4      cpu=12,gres/gpu=3                      12        3
5                                             8         0
6                                             9         0
7      cpu=13,gres/gpu=4,gres/gpu:ret6000=2   20        4
8      mem=12G,gres/gpu=3,gres/gpu:1080ti=1   21        3
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: `awk` do not need `cat`, it could read files on its' own. Combining `cat` and `awk` is generally discouraged as *useless use of cat*.

For this task I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
cpu=1,mem=256G
cpu=2,mem=1024M

cpu=12,gres/gpu=3


cpu=13,gres/gpu=4,gres/gpu:ret6000=2
mem=12G,gres/gpu=3,gres/gpu:1080ti=1
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="gres/gpu="}{print $2+0}' file.txt
```

output

```
0
0
0
3
0
0
4
3
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is `gres/gpu=` then for each line I do print 2nd field increased by zero. For lines without `gres/gpu=` `$2` is empty string, when used in arithmetic context this is same as zero so zero plus zero gives zero. For lines with at least one `gres/gpu=` increasing by zero provokes GNU `AWK` to find longest prefix which is legal number, thus `3` (4th line) becomes `3`, `4,` (7th line) becomes `4`, `3,` (8th line) becomes `3`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to have a more complete example. Can you help me to revise you answer to the new question?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples in GNU `awk` you can try following code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be using `awk`'s `match` function where using regex `gres\/gpu=([0-9]+)`(escaping `/` here) and creating one and only capturing group to capture all digits coming after `=`. Once match is found printing current line followed by array's arr's 1st element `+0`(to print zero in case no match found for any line) here.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print $0,"GPUAllocated"
  next
}
{
  match($0,/gres\/gpu=([0-9]+)/,arr)
  print $0,arr[1]+0
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS="\t"} 
    NR==1{
        $(NF+1)="GPUAllocated"
    }
    NR>1{
        $(NF+1)=FS 0
    } 
    /gres\/gpu=/{
        split($0, a, "=")
        gp=a[3]; gsub(/[ ,].*/, "", gp)  
        $NF=FS gp
    }1' test.text 

Index  AllocTres                              CPUTotal GPUAllocated
1      cpu=1,mem=256G                         18        0
2      cpu=2,mem=1024M                        16        0
3                                             4         0
4      cpu=12,gres/gpu=3                      12        3
5                                             8         0
6                                             9         0
7      cpu=13,gres/gpu=4,gres/gpu:ret6000=2   20        4
8      mem=12G,gres/gpu=3,gres/gpu:1080ti=1   21        3
```